# Power Query. improving performance while remaining flexible in input

Tags: performance, powerbi, query-optimization, powerquery

I have been doing research relating to query performances and I have read that any unused column should be suppressed in order to optimise a query.

Thus, I should take insert a "remove columns" step in my query and I would thus improve performance.

However, I did some tests and noticed that if I would have a new file with some of the columns that I am supressing in my steps already suppressed (for one reason or another), this leads to issues to my query.

I was wondering how it could be possible to set up the query with more flexibility.

I see the following possibilities to improve my queries:

- Using **Table.SelectColumns** rather than **Table.RemoveColumns** : but this makes my query really horribly long.
- Using the parameters of **Table.RemoveColumns**. But I have trouble understanding the difference between the effects of **MissingField.Ignore** or **MissingField.UseNull**

Here is a sample data:

```
  |------------------|---------------------|-----------------|-------------|    
  |       Wourf      |         Nap         |     Banzai      |  Hypernup   | 
  |------------------|---------------------|-----------------|-------------|
  |      0563        |        Nap3343      |      Picolo     |    Hyper    |    
  |------------------|---------------------|-----------------|-------------|
  |     0            |       Coniglio      |      Grasso     |    Super    | 
  |------------------|---------------------|-----------------|-------------|
  |     0563         |        Nao34        |     Dimagritto  |     Hyper   |             
  |------------------|---------------------|-----------------|-------------|
```

And here is a sample code. Typically, the "**Wourf**" or "**Nap**" could be suppressed, because they are not used in the query. But I could also get a data source with columns already missing, therefore leading to issues :

```
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Promoted Headers",{"Nap", "Wourf"}),
```

Here is my current solution:

```
 #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Promoted Headers",{"Nap", "Wourf"}, MissingField.Ignore),
```

Is there a better solution that I do not know?

Comment: Hi, your question is too general. I suggest you to include the code you're using and some sample data.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added a sample data as well as some code.

Comment: How many columns do you need to select? are they always the same? Are they in the same position? Removed columns has that disadvantage though you could use a `Try catch` approach. What do you mean with `horribly long`? time or length?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. The sample I provided is reduced, but I would need to select around 20 columns over a file of maybe 60 columns which change positions from time to time, and which are not used later on. By horribly long, I mean that I first tried to list all columns that I always wanted to keep, which means that my query was less readable. It was also slow as well when running my query but I would not think the two issues are related. If anything, the query executed a bit faster with this method (well less slowly at least). I have not see anything on "catch", I will research this.

Comment: The safe path is to select the columns you're going to keep. I understand that it's less readable, but that's only one step.

Comment: Ok, thank you. This strategy is thus better than `Table.RemoveColumns(#"Promoted Headers",{"Nap", "Wourf"}, MissingField.Ignore)` ?